# Why is DJI Mobile SDK waypoint mission vertical speed limited to -0.5m/s while descending?

Tags: dji-sdk

At some point during the summer the DJI Waypoint missions in our applications seem to be now limited to -0.5m/s vertical speed. Going up as fast as usual, but going down is really slooooow.

We're still trying to figure out if it's a firmware or SDK version issue. Is there now a limit in the SDK of firmware? Any way around that limit?

Platform: Inspire 2 + X5S